# Ajudar com rgss3 Sistema de move para coord do mouse

Tags: rgss3

boa galera vim pedir ajudar de alguns de voces com um sistema que tem no hutommo_ace.

Andei funçando o Sistema do personagem se move pela coord no mouse do jogo, conseguir por ate no meu jogo "Scripts".

so que porem nao to conseguindo fazelo funcionar, as configurção so bem complexa.

Download: http://www.mediafire.com/file/6pqh6tpbm6tq509/hutommo_ace.rar

```css
#==============================================================================
# ◆ Mouse_Position (Input)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 　マウスの座標を取得するオブジェクト (Input 内部で使用します。)
#==============================================================================

class Mouse_Position
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ (！※ Sem proibição ※！)
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def self.inherited( subclass ) 
    __cannot_inherited( subclass )
  end
  private_class_method(:inherited)
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Variável de instância pública
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  attr_reader :x   # マウス X 座標
  attr_reader :y   # マウス Y 座標
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● オブジェクト初期化
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def initialize
    @x = -1
    @y = -1
    @pos = "\x00" * 8
    begin
      # マウスカーソルの座標を取得
      @getmouse = Win32API.new('WFInput','getMouseCursorPos','p','i')
      # マウスカーソルをセット
      @setmouse = Win32API.new('WFInput','setMouseCursorPos',%w(l l),'i')
      # マウスカーソル表示
      @show_cursor = Win32API.new('user32', 'ShowCursor', 'l', 'l')
    rescue Exception
      # 取得失敗
      raise( LoadError , "cannot read modules.",caller(0))
    end
    # 画面外のとき、表示。 画面内のとき、非表示
    @showing = true
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● マウスカーソルを表示
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_show
    @show_cursor.call(1)
    @showing = true
    nil
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● マウスカーソルを非表示
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_hide
    @show_cursor.call(0)
    @showing = false
    nil
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Obter a posição do cursor do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_mouse_pos
    unless Input.mouse_enabled?
      # Quando não estiver usando o mouse
      mouse_show
      @x = -1
      @y = -1
      return false
    end
    unless (@getmouse.call(@pos)).zero?
      # Quando há um cursor na tela
      @x , @y = @pos.unpack('ll')
      mouse_hide
      return true
    else
      # Se não estiver na tela ou inválido
      mouse_show
      @x = -1
      @y = -1
      return false
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Definir a posição do cursor do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def set_mouse_pos( x , y )
    return false unless Input.mouse_enabled?
    get_mouse_pos unless (@setmouse.call( x , y )).zero?
  end
end
#==============================================================================
# ◆ Input (再定義) ( Global module )
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 　入力の再定義(追加)です。
#==============================================================================

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Variável de classe
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @@keyboard = "\x00" * 256       # Buffer de chave
  @@old_keyboard = @@keyboard.dup # Buffer de chave (entrada anterior)
  @@nouse_mouse = "\x00" * 4
  @@nouse_mouse2 = "\x00" * 20
  # Botão do mouse
  @@mouse_input = "\x00" * 20
  # Roda
  @@wheel = "\x00" * 4

  begin
    # API para copiar o estado da chave virtual para o buffer especificado
    @@keyboard_state = Win32API.new('user32', 'GetKeyboardState', 'p', 'i')
    # Aquisição: Teclado GetKeyBoardState (Win32API) Mouse DirectInput8
    @@input_state = Win32API.new('WFInput','getInput', %w(p p p),'l')
  rescue Exception
    # Não foi possível obter
    raise( LoadError , "cannot read modules.",caller(0))
  end
  begin
    @@getpad = Win32API.new("winmm","joyGetPosEx", %w(l p), "l")
  rescue Exception
    # Não foi possível obter
    raise( LoadError , "cannot read modules.(winmm.dll)",caller(0))
  end
  #Estrutura do joypad
  @@joyinfo1 = "\x00" * 52
  @@joyinfo2 = "\x00" * 52

  # O estado do joypad
  @@joy1 = []
  @@joy2 = []

  @@joybtn1 = 0
  @@joybtn2 = 0
  @@joybtn1p = 0
  @@joybtn2p = 0

  @@keyrepeat = Hash.new
  @@joy1repeat = Hash.new
  @@joy2repeat = Hash.new
  
  @@keyrepeat.default = 0
  @@joy1repeat.default = 0
  @@joy2repeat.default = 0
  
  @@key_repeat_flag = Hash.new
  @@joy1_repeat_flag = Hash.new
  @@joy2_repeat_flag = Hash.new

  # Coordenadas do mouse
  @@mouse = Mouse_Position.new
  
  @@mouse_use = false
  @@mouse_enabled = false
  
  # A partir deste ponto, definido como uma função de módulo
  module_function
end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Julgamento de usabilidade de mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_enabled?
    @@mouse_use
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Julgamento de usabilidade de mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_use=(mouse_use)
    @@mouse_use = mouse_use ? true : false
    nil
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Coordenada X do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_x
    @@mouse.x
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Coordenada Y do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_y
    @@mouse.y
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Mostrar cursor do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_show
    @@mouse.mouse_show
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Obter rotação de roda
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def wheel_moved?
    ( self.wheel_move ).zero? ? false : true
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Obter velocidade de rotação da roda
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def wheel_move
    (@@wheel.unpack("l")).at(0)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se o botão do mouse foi pressionado
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def di_mouse_press?( button )
    if rpgvxace?
      @@mouse_input[button].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
    else
      @@mouse_input[button] >= 0x92
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Conjunto de coordenadas do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def set_mouse_pos( x , y )
    @@mouse.set_mouse_pos( x , y )
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Obter status do joypad
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_update( player = 0 )
    ret = 0
    if player.zero?
      @@joy1_repeat_flag.clear
      @@joybtn1p = @@joybtn1
      @@joyinfo1 = [ 52 , 0xff, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].pack("I*")
      if (ret = @@getpad.call( 0 , @@joyinfo1 )).zero?
        @@joy1 = @@joyinfo1.unpack("I*")
        btn = joy_cross_value( joy_dir8( 0 , 0))
        @@joybtn1 = @@joy1.at(8)
        @@joybtn1 |= btn
        true
      else
        false
      end
    else
      @@joy2_repeat_flag.clear
      @@joybtn2p = @@joybtn2
      @@joyinfo2 = [ 52 , 0xff, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].pack("I*")
      if (ret = @@getpad.call( 1 , @@joyinfo2 )).zero?
        @@joy2 = @@joyinfo2.unpack("I*")
        btn = joy_cross_value( joy_dir8( 1 , 0))
        @@joybtn2 = @@joy2.at(8)
        @@joybtn2 |= btn
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Atualização de quadro (teclado / mouse)
  # ※ Nota: Existem chaves duplicadas.
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def exupdate
    @@old_keyboard.replace( @@keyboard ) # 置き換えを強制
    @@key_repeat_flag.clear
    unless @@mouse.get_mouse_pos
      # Rato inválido
      if (@@keyboard_state.call( @@keyboard ) ).zero?
        @@keyboard.replace( @@old_keyboard )
      else
        @@keyboard[Mouse::Left , 4 ] = @@nouse_mouse
        @@old_keyboard[Mouse::Left , 4 ] = @@nouse_mouse
      end
      if @@mouse_enabled
        @@mouse_enabled = false
        @@keyboard[Mouse::Left , 4 ] = @@nouse_mouse
        @@old_keyboard[Mouse::Left , 4 ] = @@nouse_mouse
        @@wheel[ 0, 4] = @@nouse_mouse
        @@mouse_input[0 , 20] = @@nouse_mouse2
      end
    else
      # Mouse é eficaz
      unless (@@input_state.call( @@keyboard , @@wheel , @@mouse_input )).zero?
        # Não foi possível obter
        #
      end
      @@mouse_enabled = true unless @@mouse_enabled
    end
    joy_update( 0 )
    joy_update( 1 ) if JOYPAD_2P
    nil
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Atualização de quadros
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def allupdate
    update
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se a chave específica do mouse está sendo pressionada (Win32API)
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def mouse_press?
    return true if vk_press?( Mouse::Left )
    return true if vk_press?( Mouse::Right )
    return true if vk_press?( Mouse::Middle )
    return false
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se a tecla específica do joypad está sendo pressionada atualmente
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_press?( key , player = 0 )
    return false unless JOYPAD[key]
    if player.zero?
      return (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn1).zero? ? false : true
    else
      return (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn2).zero? ? false : true
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se uma tecla específica do joypad é pressionada novamente
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_trigger?( key , player = 0 )
    return false unless JOYPAD[key]
    if player.zero?
      if (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn1p).zero?
        return (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn1).zero? ? false : true
      else
        return false
      end
    else
      if (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn2p).zero?
        return (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn2).zero? ? false : true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se a tecla específica do joypad está sendo pressionada ou não
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_repeat?( key , player = 0 )
    return false unless JOYPAD[key]
    if player.zero?
      if (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn1p).zero?
        v = (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn1).zero? ? false : true
        @@joy1repeat[key] = 0
      else
        v = (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn1).zero? ? false : true
        if v
          unless @@joy1_repeat_flag[key]
            @@joy1repeat[key] += 1
            @@joy1_repeat_flag[key] = true
          end
        else
          @@joy1repeat[key] = 0
        end
        v = repeat_true?( @@joy1repeat[key] , v )
      end
    else
      if (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn2p).zero?
        v = (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn2).zero? ? false : true
        @@joy2repeat[key] = 0
      else
        v = (JOYPAD[key] & @@joybtn2).zero? ? false : true
        if v
          unless @@joy2_repeat_flag[key]
            @@joy2repeat[key] += 1
            @@joy2_repeat_flag[key] = true
          end
        else
          @@joy2repeat[key] = 0
        end
        v = repeat_true?( @@joy2repeat[key] , v )
      end
    end
    v
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Entrada de 4 vias do joypad
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_dir4( player = 0 , axis = 0)
    x, y = axis.zero? ? get_xy(player) : 
           (axis == 1 ? get_zr(player) : get_uv(player)) 
    return 0 if x.abs == y.abs
    if x.abs > y.abs
      if x > 0
        return 6
      elsif x < 0
        return 4
      else
        return 0 # x = 0 -> y = 0
      end
    elsif y > 0
      return 2
    elsif y < 0
      return 8
    else
      return 0 # y = 0 -> x = 0
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Entrada de direção do Joypad 8
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_dir8( player = 0 , axis = 0)
    x, y = axis.zero? ? get_xy(player) : 
           (axis == 1 ? get_zr(player) : get_uv(player)) 
    unless x.zero?
      arg = ( Math.atan( y.to_f / x.to_f ) * 8 ) / Math::PI
      if arg < -3
        return x > 0 ? 8 : 2
      elsif arg < -1
        return x > 0 ? 9 : 1
      elsif arg < 1
        return x > 0 ? 6 : 4
      elsif arg < 3
        return x > 0 ? 3 : 7
      else
        return x > 0 ? 2 : 8
      end
    else
      if y > 0
        return 2
      elsif y < 0
        return 8
      else
        return 0
      end
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● POV O estado
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def getpov(player = 0)
    player.zero? ? @@joy1.at(10) : @@joy2.at(10)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● POV Entrada de direção do State Joypad 8
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def pov2joy8(player = 0)
    pos = getpov(player)
    if pos <= 2250
      8
    elsif pos <= 6750
      9
    elsif pos <= 11250
      6
    elsif pos <= 15750
      3
    elsif pos <= 20250
      2
    elsif pos <= 24750
      1
    elsif pos <= 29250
      4
    elsif pos <= 33750
      7
    elsif pos < 36000
      8
    else
      0
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se uma tecla específica no teclado está sendo pressionada atualmente
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_press?( key )
    if rpgvxace?
      @@keyboard[ key ].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
    else
      @@keyboard[ key ] >= 0x92
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se uma tecla específica no teclado é pressionada recentemente
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_trigger?( key ) 
    if rpgvxace?
      unless @@old_keyboard[ key ].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
        @@keyboard[ key ].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
      else
        false
      end
    else
      unless @@old_keyboard[ key ] >= 0x92
        @@keyboard[ key ] >= 0x92
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se uma tecla específica no teclado está sendo pressionada ou não
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_repeat?( key ) 
    if rpgvxace?
      unless @@old_keyboard[ key ].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
        v = @@keyboard[ key ].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
        @@keyrepeat[key] = 0
      else
        v = @@keyboard[ key ].unpack("C").at(0) >= 0x92
        if v
          unless @@key_repeat_flag[key]
            @@keyrepeat[key] += 1
            @@key_repeat_flag[key] = true
          end
        else
          @@keyrepeat[key] = 0
        end
        v = repeat_true?( @@keyrepeat[key] , v )
      end
    else
      unless @@old_keyboard[ key ] >= 0x92
        v = @@keyboard[ key ] >= 0x92
        @@keyrepeat[key] = 0
      else
        v = @@keyboard[ key ] >= 0x92
        if v
          unless @@key_repeat_flag[key]
            @@keyrepeat[key] += 1
            @@key_repeat_flag[key] = true
          end
        else
          @@keyrepeat[key] = 0
        end
        v = repeat_true?( @@keyrepeat[key] , v )
      end
    end
    v
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se há entrada de teclado
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_input?
    if rpgvxace?
      input_num = -1
      until (input_num = @@keyboard.index(VK_INPUT_MATCH),(input_num + 1)).nil?
        return true if input_num != '0x19' and input_num.unpack("C").at(0) < 0xf0
      end
      false
    else
      input_num = -1
      until (input_num = @@keyboard.index(VK_INPUT_MATCH),(input_num + 1)).nil?
        return true if input_num != 0x19 and input_num < 0xf0
      end
      false
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Se há entrada de teclado
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_input_num
    if rpgvxace?
      input_num = -1
      until (input_num = @@keyboard.index(VK_INPUT_MATCH),(input_num + 1)).nil?
        return input_num if input_num != 0x19 and input_num.unpack("C").at(0) < 0xf0
      end
      0
    else
      input_num = -1
      until (input_num = @@keyboard.index(VK_INPUT_MATCH),(input_num + 1)).nil?
        return input_num if input_num != 0x19 and input_num < 0xf0
      end
      0
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Entrada de teclado de saída
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_input_list
    result = []
    val = -1
    i = 0
    until ( val = @@keyboard.index(VK_INPUT_MATCH,(val + 1))).nil?
      val = rpgvxace? ? val.unpack("C").at(0) : val
      if val >= 0xf0
        break
      elsif val == 0x19
        next
      elsif val >= 0x10 and val <= 0x12
        # Shift Ctrl Alt caso (Input.VK_press?)
        result[i] = val
      else
        unless @@old_keyboard[ val ] >= 0x92
          # Qualquer outra entrada válida (Input.VK_trigger?)
          result[i] = val
        end
      end
      i += 1
    end
    result
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Caps Lock O estado
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  def caps_lock?
    if rpgvxace?
      @@keyboard[ VK_CAPS ].unpack("C").at(0) & 0x01 == 0x01
    else
      @@keyboard[ VK_CAPS ] & 0x01 == 0x01
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Limpar informações de entrada do teclado
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def vk_clear
    @@keyboard = "\x00" * 256
    @@old_keyboard.replace( @@keyboard ) # Substituição de força
    nil
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Entrar determinação da chave
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def decision_trigger?
    trigger?(DECISION_KEY)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Cancelar determinação da entrada principal
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def cancel_trigger?
    trigger?(CANCEL_KEY)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Chave de decisão ou decisão Determinação de entrada de clique do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def decition_with_mouse?
    trigger?(DECISION_KEY) or vk_trigger?(DECISION_MOUSE_CLICK)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ● Cancelar chave ou cancelar o julgamento da entrada do clique do mouse
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def cancel_with_mouse?
    trigger?(CANCEL_KEY) or vk_trigger?(CANCEL_MOUSE_CLICK)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ Obter coordenadas x, y
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_xy( player = 0 )
    if player.zero?
      x = @@joy1.at(2) - 32767
      y = @@joy1.at(3) - 32767
    else
      x = @@joy2.at(2) - 32767
      y = @@joy2.at(3) - 32767
    end
    x = 0 if x.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    y = 0 if y.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    return x, y
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ Obter coordenadas z, r
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_zr( player = 0 )
    if player.zero?
      z = @@joy1.at(4) - 32767
      r = @@joy1.at(5) - 32767
    else
      z = @@joy2.at(4) - 32767
      r = @@joy2.at(5) - 32767
    end
    z = 0 if z.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    r = 0 if r.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    return z, r
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ u,v座標を取得
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_uv( player = 0 )
    if player.zero?
      u = @@joy1.at(6) - 32767
      v = @@joy1.at(7) - 32767
    else
      u = @@joy2.at(6) - 32767
      v = @@joy2.at(7) - 32767
    end
    u = 0 if u.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    v = 0 if v.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    return u, v
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ x,y,z座標を取得
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_xyz( player = 0 )
    if player.zero?
      x = @@joy1.at(2) - 32767
      y = @@joy1.at(3) - 32767
      z = @@joy1.at(4) - 32767
    else
      x = @@joy2.at(2) - 32767
      y = @@joy2.at(3) - 32767
      z = @@joy2.at(4) - 32767
    end
    p z
    x = 0 if x.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    y = 0 if y.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    z = 0 if z.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    return x, y, z
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ r,u,v座標を取得
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_ruv( player = 0 )
    if player.zero?
      r = @@joy1.at(5) - 32767
      u = @@joy1.at(6) - 32767
      v = @@joy1.at(7) - 32767
    else
      r = @@joy2.at(5) - 32767
      u = @@joy2.at(6) - 32767
      v = @@joy2.at(7) - 32767
    end
    r = 0 if r.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    u = 0 if u.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    v = 0 if v.abs < MINIMUM_LEVEL
    return r, u, v
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ◆ ジョイパッドの方向を変換
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def joy_cross_value( value )
    case value
    when 1
      return (JOYPAD[DOWN] | JOYPAD[LEFT])
    when 2
      return JOYPAD[DOWN]
    when 3
       return (JOYPAD[DOWN] | JOYPAD[RIGHT])
    when 4
      return JOYPAD[LEFT]
    when 6
      return JOYPAD[RIGHT]
    when 7
      return (JOYPAD[UP] | JOYPAD[LEFT])
    when 8
      return JOYPAD[UP]
    when 9
      return (JOYPAD[UP] | JOYPAD[RIGHT])
    else
      return 0
    end
```

so que o meu jogo troca dados com servidor e pelo que deu para entender é que o sistema ela intrepreta as coord do mouse e tranforma em um tal direção.

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Checks the status of the directional buttons, translates the data into
  # a specialized 4-direction input format, and returns the number pad
  # equivalent (2, 4, 6, 8).
  #
  # If no directional buttons are being pressed (or the equivalent), returns 0.
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def self.dir4
    return 2 if self.press?(DOWN)
    return 4 if self.press?(LEFT)
    return 6 if self.press?(RIGHT)
    return 8 if self.press?(UP)
    return 2 if self.press?(KEYMAP[:LETTER_S])
    return 4 if self.press?(KEYMAP[:LETTER_A])
    return 6 if self.press?(KEYMAP[:LETTER_D])
    return 8 if self.press?(KEYMAP[:LETTER_W])
    return 0
  end
```

por isso seria mas facil usar esse sistema ja que as direçoes ja ta sendo enviada para o servidor quando o mouse e apertado em tal coord.  ele converte a coord do mouse em self.dir4.